# Customized logging in HuggingFace

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am running the NER tutorials provided by HuggingFace official repo (see [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/token-classification/run_ner.py)). The following info is printed during the training process

```
{'loss': 0.0724, 'learning_rate': 3.8425925925925924e-05, 'epoch': 0.69}        
{'loss': 0.0315, 'learning_rate': 2.6851851851851855e-05, 'epoch': 1.39}        
{'loss': 0.0198, 'learning_rate': 1.527777777777778e-05, 'epoch': 2.08}         
{'loss': 0.0147, 'learning_rate': 3.7037037037037037e-06, 'epoch': 2.78}        
{'train_runtime': 228.6028, 'train_samples_per_second': 9.449, 'epoch': 3.0}
```

Now I would like to also print out validation metrics after each epoch. I checked out the `TrainingArguments()` [doc](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/trainer.html#trainingarguments), but it seems that the only related options are the following and **none** of them are related to the contents of logging

- `logging_dir`
- `logging_strategy`
- `logging_first_step`
- `logging_steps`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the custom callback mechanism like this: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/callback#transformers.TrainerCallback.example

just clone the function on_log and rename it to on_evaluate, this callback function will be triggered when the trainer finishes each evaluation process (maybe after each eval_step or eval_epochs, which depends on your training arguments)